# executing PHP CRON job from root while requiring a public file

Tags: php, cron, document-root

I'm working on a shared hosting environment.  I'd like to run a CRON job outside of my public_html folder.  What I did was added a folder to the root of my shared account with the CRON script I want to run.

In order for my CRON script to run properly it needs to include a file that is located in the public_html folder.

this is the general file structure on my server:

Cron script file located on the root level:

`/shared/root/cronJobs/my-script.php`

required file located in the public_html folder:

`/shared/root/public_html/sub-folder/required-file.php`

---

in `my-script.php` i'm using the following script to try and access my required file:

`require_once("../public_html/sub-folder/required-file.php");`

The above code returns the following error:

> Warning: require_once(../public_html/sub-folder/required-file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /shared/root/cronJobs/my-script.php on line 2

I've also tried:

`require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/sub-folder/required-file.php");`

The above code results in the following error:

> Warning: require_once(/sub-folder/required-file.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /shared/root/cronJobs/my-script.php on line 2

When I attempt to access my required file from inside my public_html file I don't receive any errors at all.  This is the first time I've attempted store a script away from the public folder and attempt to include a file located in the public folder.

`my-script.php` has the permissions set to 755

I just wondering if I'm doing something wrong or is what I'm attempting to do not allowed in the server environment?

Comment: I always like to require/include starting with `__DIR__` [Magic Constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). Avoids the hassle if php is executing from cron, or apache.

Comment: If you are literrally using cron to the php file (IE not doing a url call) - Cron jobs are not executed in the script directory. The working directory of cron is the home directory of the user's executing it. It should work if you use `/full/path/to/php-file.php`. If you are depending on the path at some other levels, you could use `chdir();` in `my-script.php` to change the current working directory.

Comment: `require_once("../public_html/sub-folder/required-file.php");` equals to `/shared/root/cronJobs/public_html/sub-folder/required-file.php` - a path which doesn't exist. Try `require_once("../../public_html/sub-folder/required-file.php");`

Comment: thanks @vnt you were correct.  Freaking file paths always screw me up!